# Difference between direction of ramming in hydraulic press?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, hydraulics

In Printed circuit board/Plywood lamination Hydraulic Press machines ([seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bz8bu_vZM6c)).

The ramming action comes from bottom in all the machines I saw so far. For such action from bottom, excavation has to be done. Is such excavation mandatory in ramming from bottom?

Will there be any difference if we do such ramming from top ?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the retract portion of the cycle (and perhaps the default power off condition). With the cylinders below, the pistons extend up under power but can retract (and stay retracted) with minimal or no power. The power off default is retracted. This protects the piston and may make it easier to service. I believe it is somewhat safer to have the press move to open if there's a hydraulic failure rather than move to close.

Comment: Suppose the things are other way around, then how do you separate the plates afterwards ? you need at lest twee hydraulic pens, to push them upward, so anyway you need to excavate to incorporate those pens, and you need at least four piston here.

Comment: @BobT Your comment has a potential to be the answer, it's up to you to include my suggestion as wel. If you post an answer i'll up vote it.

Comment: I was told it has to do with structural stability ie to avoid torsion and vibrations of cylinder, ground is dug and cylinder is burried.. I don't know if its exactly the reason.

Comment: @Ramki, Stability could be the reason, but i don't see anything here to rotate the cylinders, cylinders are free to rotate along their axis, so no torsion. It is just a simple hydraulic press. The housing of hydraulic presses are so massive that dumps any vibration thanks to its huge wall thickness and cast iron.

Comment: @Sam Farjamirad : Could it be to make those Platens accessible to human height that they dig for this cylinder? Thanks for clearing that torsion point.

Comment: @Ramki, i've never thought about it that way, but seems reasonable. When we design a machine, like hydraulic preses, the first thing we do is too keep our design as efficient as possible. As Bob T stated, in this configuration cylinders retract under their own weight, it means no power is needed to retract them,  and as i said before, hydraulic presses with top to bottom configuration require a massive housing, to dump vibration and prevent any considerable elastic deformation of components, however such massive housing is unnecessary in this configuration, the ground is stiff enough.

Comment: @Sam Farjamirad: Well put Sam.I understood ramming from top.Is there any way to avoid excavation in bottom ramming? I have one business proposal . If interested let me know. I am at r a p o l i i t at g m a i l dot c o m. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ramki Interesting question, and how do you fix it in place? you know hydraulic machines start moving around, action and reaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81267/discussion-between-ramki-and-sam-farjamirad).